# Como ver se um usuário curtiu ou não minha página com javascript?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

Fiquei impressionado de não encontrar esta pergunta em similar questions. O fato, porém, é que eu já encontrei esta pergunta várias vezes em inglês neste site, e nenhuma das soluções apresentadas resolveram meu problema. Talvez porque essas perguntas que encontrei em inglês sejam antigas, e o facebook vive atualizando as formas de se utilizar o facebook javascript SDK. Quero saber como é que hoje eu faço para saber se um determinado usuário curtiu ou não minha página pelo facebook JS SDK. Estou cansado de procurar a solução na internet e nada funcionar. Meu código para isso não funciona. Eis o código:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
        try {
            FB.init({
                appId  : '{meu_ap_id}',
                status : true, // check login status
                cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                version: 'v5.0'
            });
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e.message);
        }
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response['status'] == 'connected') {
                token = response['authResponse']['accessToken'];
                FB.api('/me/likes/{page-id}', 'get', {access_token: token} function(result) {
                    alert(result);
                    if (result){ 
                        alert('is fan');
                    } else alert ('not a fan');
                }); */
            }
        });

    });
```

O init() funciona. O getLoginStatus() também funciona, retornando 'connected' (isso depois de eu ter salvado na configuração do meu aplicativo a url do meu site como url de redirecionamento válida para OAuth2. Já o FB.api(), como exposto no código não funciona. Alguém sabe dizer o que está errado no meu FB.api(), ou também em outra parte do código? Por exemplo: o alert(result) que coloquei dentro da função de callback para testar o código não executa, dando a entender que tudo dentro de FB.api não executa. Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: Quero dizer que já encontrei de cara dois erros de sintaxe neste código. Bem. agora o código só retorna "is fan", mesmo eu não tendo curtido a página.

Comment: melhor ler a documentação da api do Facebook, lá está atualizado e inclusive em português: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v6.0/object/likes

Answer (score 0):

Ricardo Pontual, li a documentação e apliquei a mudança. Substitui meu FB.api pelo código sugerido na página que você me passou:

```
FB.api(
                            "/340029920105070/likes", {access_token: '{app_id|{o resto do token}'},
                            function (response) {
                              alert(response.error.message);
                              if (response && !response.error) {
                                alert('sss');
                              }
                            }
                        );
```

Porém, o código sugerido na página não vinha com o access_token, o que fez com que o alert(response.error.message) retornasse um erro dizendo que eu precisaria de um app_secret ou de um app token. Passei o dia todo trabalhando nisso, Até que pareço ter resolvido o problema, mas surgiu outro problema, a saber: "(#10) This endpoint requires the 'manage_pages' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions#manage-pages and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS for details.". Eu até vou dar uma olhada nesses links sugeridos, mas, se você ou outra pessoa tiverem a solução para este problema, eu gostaria que vocês a trouxessem a mim, pois estou há muitos dias tentando resolver este problema. Grato.